# How to auto-populate fields with data from a DB based on user selection

Tags: javascript, java, database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created a form with a select field that lets the user choose a 'Special Project' from a list that is populated from a Postgres database using Spring-Boot/Thymeleaf. My question is: How do I use the value selected by the user to automatically populate the input fields for 'Project Description' and 'Project Owner' using the data in the DB that corresponds to the user's selection?

I'm a bit of a novice, so I don't know if this can be acheived with javascript or not? If not what is the general recommended route to acheive this?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="">
    <div class="modal-body">
        Special Project Name: <select name="spProject"
            th:sProject="${specialProjectList}" id="spProject"
            style="float: right; width: 200px">
            <option value="0">Select Special Project...</option>
            <option th:each="sProject : ${specialProjectList}"
                th:value="${sProject.projectname}"
                th:text="${sProject.projectname}"
                style="float: right; width: 200px"></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Project Description: <input type="text" id="projectDesc"
            name="projectDesc" style="float: right">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Project Owner: <input type="text" id="projectOwner" name="projectOwner"
            style="float: right; width: 200px">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Status: <select name="projectStatus" id="projectStatus"
            style="float: right; width: 200px">
            <option value="inProgress">Select project status...</option>
            <option value="inProgress">In Progress</option>
            <option value="complete">Complete</option>
            <option value="onHold">On Hold</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"
            data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btnA  btn-primary"></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

this can definitely be achieved using JavaScript. There's a library called jQuery, I would suggest you use it since it will make your work easier. jQuery has a function `change()` which triggers whenever you change your selection. Here's a basic implementation

```
$('#spProject').change(() => {
    // call spring controller to retrieve the data from db
});
```

Finally, jQuery also includes `ajax` which will also help you to call this controller. In `ajax` you can specify what will happen after calling the controller. I'll let you do the rest of the reseach.

So overall what I suggest you do is:

1. attach `change()` function to your `select` element
2. inside your `change()` function, call your spring controller and pass the data necessary for retrieving the information from your DB.
3. retrieve the data returned and display in the fields

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this feature using jquery AutoComplete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default Here are the steps: -

1. Fetch the required data using jquery $.ajax() and store that data into a json object.
   For that you use $document.ready() function.
2. Add the jquery AutoComplete event on that input field.

If you need any help. Post your comment below.

Here is a jsFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/6xgg4074/5/]